# php - are these functions good to reduce server load?

Tags: php, load, reduce

good evening,
i have these `five functions` that i use to `reduce server load` :

```
// unset all vars
function unset_all_vars()
{
    $vars = func_get_args();
    foreach($vars[0] as $key => $val)
    {
        unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
    }
    return serialize($vars[0]);
} 
unset_all_vars(get_defined_vars()); 

// unset all const
function unset_all_const()
{
    $vars =  func_get_args();
    foreach($vars[0] as $key => $val)
    {
        unset($key);
    }
    return serialize($vars[0]);
} 
unset_all_const(get_defined_constants()); 

// unset all functions
function unset_all_functions()
{
    $vars =  func_get_args();
    foreach($vars[0] as $key => $val)
    {
        unset($key);
    }
    return serialize($vars[0]);
} 
unset_all_functions(get_defined_functions()); 

// unset all classes
function unset_all_classes()
{
    $vars =  func_get_args();
    foreach($vars[0] as $x => $v)
    {
        unset($x);
    }
    return serialize($vars[0]);
} 
unset_all_classes(get_declared_classes()); 

// unset all interfaces
function unset_all_interfaces()
{
    $vars =  func_get_args();
    foreach($vars[0] as $x => $v)
    {
        unset($x);
    }
    return serialize($vars[0]);
} 
unset_all_interfaces(get_declared_interfaces());

?>
```

function 1 unset all vars
function 2 unset all const
function 3 unset all functions
function 4 unset all classes
function 5 unset all interfaces

are they good ?
is there some other functions `better than` them ? or `additional to` them ?

Comment: These functions are just going to _increase_ server load.

Comment: This is really *totally* ridiculous.

Comment: Something named `unset_*()` has a return value? You can "unset" functions, classes, methods and even constants? You want to reduce server load by executing additional code and especially by using `serialize()`? Sorry to tell you, but you don't know, what you are talking about ... None of them makes sense...

Comment: All you're doing is wasting CPU cycles doing a bit of "cleanup" that PHP would already do far more efficiently itself when the script exits. Unless you're doing a long-running script (e.g. hours/days), then this can only HURT your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use functions like this at all? Even if they would work, a PHP script runs only for a second at most, after which it will clear up everything it has allocated. Freeing things inbetween is particularly useful for scripts that run for a long time and allocate lots of resources that are soon not needed anymore, but this is quite uncommon for web pages, for which PHP is mainly used.

The naming is wrong too, since they don't deallocate 'all' items, but only the ones they are passed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `unset` (or more correctly, `undefine`) a constant, function, class or interface. Nor should you ever need to - it certainly wouldn't "reduce server load", even if you could. And I can't see unsetting all the variables in the global scope making any real positive difference - if you create a large variable and want to free up the resources it has used after use then do it explicitly at the time, unsetting all global variables is highly unlikely to do any good, and it will probably cause harm.

Further to this, all your functions apart from the first one have no effect whatsoever. In a foreach, the variables that are created during the loop are copies of the original data, and unsetting the copy does not affect the original.

PHP is garbage collected so you shouldn't ever need to worry about things like this - read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).